# NullPointer exception in scheduled method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I want to insert some data into my DB. But I catch

```
"ERROR: org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

I don't know what to do.

```
public class HeadHunterImport {
    @Autowired
    private static HeadHunterService headHunterService;


    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 600000)

    public void AsyncRemovalOldData() {
        headHunterService.addHeadHunter("Moscow", 100, 100) ;  

    }
```

If I'll call it in controller it will work fine. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(headHunterService!=null){
         headHunterService.addHeadHunter("Moscow", 100, 100) ; 
 }else{

      Sysem.out.println("headHunterService Object is null");
 }
```

if headHunterService return null please make sure the following code present in your context.

```
   <context:annotation-config/>

   <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.name.here"/>
```

Make sure the following class annotate with @Component

```
  @Component
  class HeadHunterService {

  }

or 

you need the setter injection for headHunterService
```

Comment: To be honset, it's not the real answer, but `if(headHunterService!=null)` made me think to delete `static` statement. So I will select you.